# ClientError (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when trying to upload file to Amazon S3 from an EC2 instance in a Flask app

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, flask

I'm trying to write a Flask app to upload to an AWS S3 bucket. Where, when I run this locally in PyCharm it works fine. However, once I deployed it to AWS (deploying the Flask app on port 80) I now get an error...

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The request sture we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

When the keys work locally...but don't work on the AWS EC2 instance. Some of my initial thoughts were maybe a port issue or an issue with boto3. Though I'm not sure because it works locally, just not on AWS.

Any help? Here is my code...with keys and URLs removed ofc

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired
from tools import s3_upload

'''
Author: xxx
'''

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
# Flask Secret Key
app.secret_key = 'xxxxx'

# Limits what file types can be uploaded
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

# Initializes upload form
class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    example = FileField(validators=[FileRequired()])

# Route for root, handles on click action for upload form
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_page():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        file = form.example.data
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        output = s3_upload(file,filename)
        flash('{src} uploaded to S3'.format(src=form.example.data.filename))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**tools.py**

```
import boto3
from flask import current_app as app

'''
Author: xxx
'''

def s3_upload(source_file, source_filename):
    # What directory on Amazon S3 Bucket to upload to.
    upload_dir = app.config["S3_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY"]

    #Connect to S3 and upload file
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_fileobj(source_file, app.config["S3_BUCKET"], upload_dir + "/" + source_filename)
```

**config.py**

```
S3_KEY = 'xxx'
S3_SECRET = 'xxxx'
S3_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = 'xxxx'
S3_BUCKET = 'xxxx'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif']

SECRET_KEY = "xxxx"
DEBUG = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a key issue with AWS and also a network security issue of me using a port that is blocked on the network here.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your client object to:

```
client = boto3.client('s3', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```